# Android Robolectric Click RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, robolectric, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to simulate a click on a `RecyclerView` item with Robolectric?

So far, I have tried getting the `View` at the first visible position of the `RecyclerView`, but that is always `null`. It's `getChildCount()` keeps returning `0`, and `findViewHolderForPosition` is always `null`. The adapter returns a non-0 number from `getItemCount()` (there are definitely items in the adapter).

I'm using Robolectric 2.4 SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Seems like the issue was that `RecyclerView` needs to be measured and layed out manually in Robolectric. Calling this solves the problem:

```
recyclerView.measure(0, 0);
recyclerView.layout(0, 0, 100, 10000);
```

Comment: This is a great find. Thank you for that. May I ask how you went about finding that the recycler view was not measured and laid out? It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Where do you add the measure and the layout? after the findViewById in the test itself?

Comment: There isn't one specific place to do it; I sometimes do it after `findViewById` but I'll usually do it right before I need it.

Comment: Also, this code should be called as many times as you called `notifyDatasetChanged()` or similar method on the adapter, not just once. It just happened to me.

Comment: Hi @Eliezer, thank you for the answer. I've been looking for a while and this worked. If possible, how did you figure out this? I'd like to know in order to increase my knowledge of Android.

Comment: @Eliezer Thank you for the answer. This works well for me.

Answer (score 10):

With Robolectric 3 you can use visible():

```
ActivityController<MyActivity> activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivityclass);
activityController.create().start().visible();

ShadowActivity myActivityShadow = shadowOf(activityController.get()); 

RecyclerView currentRecyclerView = ((RecyclerView) myActivityShadow.findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerid));
    currentRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).performClick();
```

This eliminates the need to trigger the measurement of the view by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on *Marco Hertwig*'s answer:

You need to add the `recyclerView` to an activity so that its layout methods are called as expected. You could call them manually, (like in *Elizer*'s answer) but you would have to manage the state yourself. Also, this would not be simulating an actual use-case.

Code:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    ActivityController<Activity> activityController = 
        Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity.class); // setup a default Activity
    Activity activity = activityController.get();

    /*
    Setup the recyclerView (create it, add the adapter, add a LayoutManager, etc.)
    ...
    */

    // set the recyclerView object as the only view in the activity
    activity.setContentView(recyclerView);

    // start the activity
    activityController.create().start().visible();
}
```

Now you don't need to worry about calling `layout` and `measure` everytime your `recyclerView` is updated (by adding/removing items from the `adapter`, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Just invoke

```
Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler()
```

before performClick() to ensure that all ui operations (including measure and layout phases of recycler view after populating with the dataset) are finished