# Rebolectric: DividerItemDecoration blocks setting measurement to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, robolectric

I am writing test cases for `RecyclerView` items using `Robolectric`.
Facing `NullPointerException` while calling [`recyclerView.measure(0,0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052866/android-robolectric-click-recyclerview-item) because `RecyclerView` have applied with `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` and it is working fine for the `RecyclerView` which is not being with `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`.

Exception Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ui.adapters.DividerItemDecoration.getItemOffsets(DividerItemDecoration.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemDecoration.getItemOffsets(RecyclerView.java:8662)
```

Placed comment in line number 119 of `DividerItemDecoration.java`, and here, `mDivider` became `NULL` which is initialized from constructor.

```
@Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, int itemPosition, RecyclerView parent) {
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());//Line:119
        } else {
            outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
        }
    }
```

Constructor

```
public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
        mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
        a.recycle();
        setOrientation(orientation);
    }
```

Where `ATTRS`

```
private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
            android.R.attr.listDivider
    };
```

Please guide me on how to write test cases for `RecyclerView` which is being with `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`, thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION:**
Finally, I resolved this issue by making `Shadow` class for `RecyclerView` as mentioned in below code and followed basic shadow mapping logic,

RecyclerViewShadow.java

```
@Implements(RecyclerView.class)
public class RecyclerViewShadow extends ShadowViewGroup {
    @Implementation
    public void addItemDecoration(RecyclerView.ItemDecoration decor, int index) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `mDivider` is null, check if `a.getDrawable()` is returning drawable.

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' Yeah, Checked that is not returning drawable, may I know why it is happening?