# Can't click on RecyclerView child in Robolectric

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, robolectric

I am writing tests for the view in an MVP android app. In these tests, I am using Robolectric 3.6.1. The problem I run into is getting a NullPointerException when I try to click on a view inside the RecyclerView with `getChildAt()`. This only happens when the whole test class is run, not when tests are run in isolation, which makes me think something in my setup is wrong. If I run the whole class the first test does not have this problem, but all the other ones do, so the problem seems to arise when the `setUp()` function is called more than once.

I did some research and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052866/android-robolectric-click-recyclerview-item) post, but putting that inside my code doesn't help.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private List<Measurement> measurements = Arrays.asList(new Measurement("Object A", Unit.CM), new Measurement("Object B", Unit.KG));
    private final int POSITION = 0;

    @Mock
    private MainMvpPresenter mainMvpPresenter;

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    private RecyclerView measurementsRecyclerView;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().visible().get();
        mainActivity.setMainMvpPresenter(mainMvpPresenter);

        measurementsRecyclerView = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.measurementsList);
        mainActivity.updateMeasurements(measurements);
    }

    @Test
    public void setUpCorrectly(){
        assertThat(measurementsRecyclerView.getChildCount(), is(measurements.size()));
    }

    @Test
    public void onItemClicked_ShouldCallPresenter() {
        measurementsRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(POSITION).itemView.performClick();
        verify(mainMvpPresenter).measurementClicked(POSITION);
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jakkaps.body_measurements.ui.main.MainActivityTest.onItemClicked_ShouldCallPresenter(MainActivityTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:535)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:249)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:123)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131
```

)

Comment: Why there is reflection is in the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really find a solution to the actual problem, I just kinda played around until it worked. The thing I had to do was to not call `measurementsRecyclerView = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.measurementsList);` in the `setUp()` function, but rather in each test separately. I also had to call  `mainActivity.updateMeasurements(measurements);` twice.

Turned out very messy, so I recommend anyone to find their own solution.